# Maintenance Expiration

Tags: blacklight-retribution

So I just bought and activated some kit and the servers went down for Maintenance... Do the timers keep ticking or do they pause the timers while the servers are down?

Answer (score -1):

Temporarily unlocked **gear only counts down on days you actually log in to the servers.** For example, if you unlock a piece of gear for three days and then take two months off from playing, you will still have two more days once you start playing again. This was quite the welcome surprise when I came back to the game after a long hiatus.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Once an item has been activated, it counts down in real time, not 'logged in' time. It IS possible, however, to have an 'inactive' time-limited item remain indefinitely until it is finally activated.